# How to use a bool Query with function_score in Elasticsearch?

Tags: php, jquery, elasticsearch, scoring, booleanquery

I have 3 types of data [doctor,article,place] which I want to match their documents based on a bool query. but I want to give doctor type a boost of 3, place type a boost of 2 and article a boost of 1.I have a search Query which uses `function_score` and `bool query` to match documents. but the problem is it throws an exception which says `No function with the name [bool] is registered.`. Here is my Query :

```
GET /my_index/doctor,article,place/_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "bool": {
                "should":
                [
                    {
                      "common": {
                        "title": {
                            "query":"$q",
                            "cutoff_frequency": 0.001,
                            "low_freq_operator": "and"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "prefix": {
                            "title": "$q"
                            }

                    },
                    {
                        "match_phrase_prefix" : {
                            "title" : {
                                "query": "$q",
                                "slop":  10
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "functions":[
                {
                    "filter":{
                        "type":{
                           "value":"doctor"
                        }
                    },
                    "weight":3
                },
                {
                    "filter":{
                        "type":{
                           "value":"place"
                        }
                    },
                    "weight":2
                },
                {
                    "filter":{
                        "type":{
                           "value":"article"
                        }
                    },
                    "weight":1
                }
            ],
            "score_mode":"first",
            "boost_mode":"multiply"
        }
    }
}
```

thanks for your help.

**EDIT** :

**ERROR :**

```
{
  "error": "SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed;
            shardFailures {[fWqkaeoLSva_QwhrYHnG3A][darmanjoo][0]:
            SearchParseException[[darmanjoo][0]: from[-1],size[-1]:
              Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
                {
                  "query": {
                    "function_score": {
                      "query": {
                        "bool": {
                          "should": [
                            {
                              "common": {
                                "title": {
                                  "query": "دکتر",
                                  "cutoff_frequency": 0.001,
                                  "low_freq_operator": "and"
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "prefix": {
                                "title": "دکتر"
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "match_phrase_prefix": {
                                "title": {
                                  "query": "دکتر",
                                  "slop": 10
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      "functions": [
                        {
                          "filter": {
                            "type": {
                              "value": "doctor"
                            }
                          },
                          "weight": 3
                        },
                        {
                          "filter": {
                            "type": {
                              "value": "place"
                            }
                          },
                          "weight": 2
                        },
                        {
                          "filter": {
                            "type": {
                              "value": "article"
                            }
                          },
                          "weight": 1
                        }
                      ],
                      "score_mode": "first",
                      "boost_mode": "multiply"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]]];
            nested: QueryParsingException[[darmanjoo] No function with the name [weight] is registered.]; }{[fWqkaeoLSva_QwhrYHnG3A][darmanjoo][1]:
            SearchParseException[[darmanjoo][1]: from[-1],size[-1]:
              Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
                {
                  "query": {
                    "function_score": {
                      "query": {
                        "bool": {
                          "should": [
                            {
                              "common": {
                                "title": {
                                  "query": "دکتر",
                                  "cutoff_frequency": 0.001,
                                  "low_freq_operator": "and"
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "prefix": {
                                "title": "دکتر"
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "match_phrase_prefix": {
                                "title": {
                                  "query": "دکتر",
                                  "slop": 10
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      "functions": [
                        {
                          "filter": {
                            "type": {
                              "value": "doctor"
                            }
                          },
                          "weight": 3
                        },
                        {
                          "filter": {
                            "type": {
                              "value": "place"
                            }
                          },
                          "weight": 2
                        },
                        {
                          "filter": {
                            "type": {
                              "value": "article"
                            }
                          },
                          "weight": 1
                        }
                      ],
                      "score_mode": "first",
                      "boost_mode": "multiply"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]]];
            nested: QueryParsingException[[darmanjoo] No function with the name [weight] is registered.]; }{[fWqkaeoLSva_QwhrYHnG3A][darmanjoo][4]:
            SearchParseException[[darmanjoo][4]: from[-1],size[-1]:
              Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [
                {
                  "query": {
                    "function_score": {
                      "query": {
                        "bool": {
                          "should": [
                            {
                              "common": {
                                "title": {
                                  "query": "دکتر",
                                  "cutoff_frequency": 0.001,
                                  "low_freq_operator": "and"
                                }
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "prefix": {
                                "title": "دکتر"
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "match_phrase_prefix": {
                                "title": {
                                  "query": "دکتر",
                                  "slop": 10
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      },
                      "functions": [
                        {
                          "filter": {
                            "type": {
                              "value": "doctor"
                            }
                          },
                          "weight": 3
                        },
                        {
                          "filter": {
                            "type": {
                              "value": "place"
                            }
                          },
                          "weight": 2
                        },
                        {
                          "filter": {
                            "type": {
                              "value": "article"
                            }
                          },
                          "weight": 1
                        }
                      ],
                      "score_mode": "first",
                      "boost_mode": "multiply"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]]];
            nested: QueryParsingException[[darmanjoo] No function with the name [weight] is registered.]; }]",
  "status": 400
}
```

**MY EDITED QUERY STRAIGHT COPIED FROM MARVEL SENSE :**

```
GET /darmanjoo/doctor,article,place/_search
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "should": [
                        {
                            "common": {
                                "title": {
                                    "query": "$q",
                                    "cutoff_frequency": 0.001,
                                    "low_freq_operator": "and"
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "prefix": {
                                "title": "$q"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "match_phrase_prefix": {
                                "title": {
                                    "query": "$q",
                                    "slop": 10
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "functions": [
                {
                    "filter": {
                        "type": {
                            "value": "doctor"
                        }
                    },
                    "weight": 3
                },
                {
                    "filter": {
                        "type": {
                            "value": "place"
                        }
                    },
                    "weight": 2
                },
                {
                    "filter": {
                        "type": {
                            "value": "article"
                        }
                    },
                    "weight": 1
                }
            ],
            "score_mode": "first",
            "boost_mode": "multiply"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen your first post (that was removed in the end) and I still don't understand what are you trying to do. Probably, you've seen the syntax on es website about `function_score` and it shouldn't surprise you the error you get. What exactly are you trying to do with your data and this query?

Comment: @AndreiStefan, I'm trying to search documents with bool query, but different boost for types of documents.

Comment: No, explain on real data. "I have doctors, articles and places and I want to..."

Comment: @AndreiStefan, done, please take a look again.

Comment: And all these three types have a `title` field?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
GET /my_index/doctor,article,place/_search
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "common": {
                "title": {
                  "query": "$q",
                  "cutoff_frequency": 0.001,
                  "low_freq_operator": "and"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "prefix": {
                "title": "$q"
              }
            },
            {
              "match_phrase_prefix": {
                "title": {
                  "query": "$q",
                  "slop": 10
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "type": {
              "value": "doctor"
            }
          },
          "boost_factor": 3
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "type": {
              "value": "place"
            }
          },
          "boost_factor": 2
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "type": {
              "value": "article"
            }
          },
          "boost_factor": 1
        }
      ],
      "score_mode": "first",
      "boost_mode": "multiply"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: now it throws another exception which says nested: QueryParsingException[[my_index] No function with the name [weight] is registered.]

Comment: That query worked for me. Make sure you copy-pasted properly.

Comment: I have triple checked my request. thanks for your try, but it gives error in EDIT SECTION of POST

Comment: What ES version are you using?

Comment: version number : "1.3.4"

Comment: also I copied my Query straight from Marvel Sense.

Comment: "weight" has been added in 1.4.0.

Comment: In pre-1.4.0.Beta1 is called `boost_factor`. I've updated my answer. Try again.